# pip install docx2html throws error

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to in install docx2html in python library using `pip install docx2html` but I am shown this traceback:

```
Collecting docx2html
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b3/a9/e943f7b36f1a8afd8b234b9e999be8837ab2666c7e743a4d527e14d39053/docx2html-0.2.3.tar.gz
Collecting lxml==2.2.4 (from docx2html)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/85/2776a729f8ef1e2aca83e02393dbdfcdf2c0f7c5a1205a77bbf1f82230f9/lxml-2.2.4.tar.gz
Collecting pillow==1.7.7 (from docx2html)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/93/d6eabe91dda55ac924c95763568d596e3e6082950a04c24fccf32c12324c/Pillow-1.7.7.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/_y/g09fpxn13xq7z6ptmq3095dm0000gn/T/pip-install-9u3p45p6/pillow/setup.py", line 162
        print "--- using Tcl/Tk libraries at", TCL_ROOT
                                            ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("--- using Tcl/Tk libraries at", TCL_ROOT)?

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_y/g09fpxn13xq7z6ptmq3095dm0000gn/T/pip-install-9u3p45p6/pillow/
```

I tried `pip install --upgrade setuptools` but setuptools are upto date.

Comment: That message is implying that the version of Pillow (Pillow-1.7.7.zip) is written in python2 (hence the lack of `()`).

Comment: Thanks @ScottMermelstein. I see your point. I can't hope to change the Pillow library to python3 syntax. Any idea how the error can be resolved?

Comment: If I had that, I'd post an answer.  :-)  Sorry, the best I could give you at this time was just that hint.

Comment: I used `pypandoc` to convert docx to html. Worked like a charm.

Comment: You may want to post that as an answer.  It's totally ok to self-answer a question.  In addition to giving you a chance to earn more reputation, it helps anyone else with the same problem see your solution without having to read the question comments.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using `pypandoc` instead of `docx2html` to convert docx to html.